# tensorflow gradients are 0 even though the loss is non-zero?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def setup_mat():
    np_data = np.asarray(
        [
            [-1, -2, -3],
            [-0.1, -0.2, -0.3],
            [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
            [1, 2, 3]
        ]
    )
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(
        np_data, dtype_hint=tf.float32)


def report_binary_xent():
    Xs = setup_mat()
    weights = tf.Variable([[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]], shape=(3, 1), trainable=True)

    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

    labels = np.asarray([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0])

    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
        g.watch([weights])
        logits = tf.matmul(Xs, weights)
        preds = tf.math.softmax(logits)
        bce_res = bce(labels, preds)
    dydx = g.gradient(bce_res, [preds, logits, weights])
    print(dydx)
```

I'd expect the gradients to be non-zero as:

1. the weights are marked as trainable
2. I'm watching the weights
3. the loss is non-zero

Could I get any insight into this? It's not immediately clear to me what's wrong

Comment: You are computing a softmax over a single-element axis (your logits have shape (4,1)). The output will always be `1`, so the gradients are 0.

Comment: D'oh I can't believe that I missed that. Thank you. I meant to do a sigmoid *facepalm*. What's the etiquette here? Mind posting it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: TBH the etiquette is that one shouldn't answer questions in the comments :) whoops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the softmax operation, you'll see what is going on.

Here is the value of `logits` before the softmax operation:

```
[[-14.       ]
 [ -1.4000001]
 [  1.4000001]
 [ 14.       ]], shape=(4, 1), dtype=float32)
```

The largest element is 14.

Here is the value of `preds` after the softmax operation:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]], shape=(4, 1), dtype=float32)
```

However, every output is 1 here. Why? It is applying a softmax operation within each row. For a 1 element array, the softmax of that array is 1, no matter what the input value is.

If you take the gradient of a 1-element softmax, it will be 0, because nothing can change the output away from 1.

I assume you meant to take the softmax across the column, instead. You can do that by adding `axis=0`.

```
preds = tf.math.softmax(logits, axis=0)
```

After doing that, I get non-zero gradients.